# make server run aspx requests with php

Tags: php, asp.net, apache2

We are creating a real estate website. The National Franchise site wants to pass us searchs that fall in out local area. The searches MUST follow this format:

```
/propertysearch/findpropreties.aspx?q1=this&q2=that&q3=other
```

The issues is that we have built a site in PHP and buying a windows server and learning aspx seems like overkill for this one script.

So... I think I need to make a redirect, like this:

```
RewriteRule /propertysearch/findpropreties.aspx$ http://texasmls.com/corpSearch.php [R=301,L,QSA]
```

But it does not work.

In summary:
Does anyone know how to trick the server into running aspx files as php?
I recieve a request like 
`example.com/propertysearch/findproperties.aspx?this=Something`
I want to parse this request with php...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged your question with apache2, so this is the Apache way:

Somewhere in your httpd.conf, site-specific .conf file, or a .htaccess, put this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .aspx
```

This'll force Apache to run any .aspx through the PHP interpreter.

Comment: You Rock! This worked just like it should, I just added - AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .aspx - with the version of php to .haccess

Comment: Now I just need my editor to recognize .aspx files as php so I can get my syntax highlighting back ^_^.

Comment: In 'vim' it'd be `:set syntax=php`. <troll>There are no other editors worth mentioning</troll>